# Make xml more readable

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, text-formatting

Is there any way to take an xml string in .net and make it easyer to read?
what i mean is can i convert this:

```
<element1><element2>some data</element2></element1>
```

to this:

```
<element1>
    <element2>
        some data
    </element2>
</element1>
```

is there any built in class for this? as sql server 2005 seems to remove all formatting on xml to save space or some thing...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can load it as an `XDocument` and then just call ToString() which will indent it appropriately. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<element1><element2>some data</element2></element1>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        xml = doc.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
<element1>
  <element2>some data</element2>
</element1>
```

If you're writing it to a file or other stream, then `XDocument.Save` will (by default) indent it too.

(I believe `XElement` has all the same features, if you don't really need an `XDocument`.)

Comment: I have this app in my \bin directory, it is called "xmlpp" for XML pretty-print.  invaluable.

Answer (score 5):

How do you save / write the XML back to a file ?

You can create an XmlWriter and pass it an XmlWriterSettings instance, where you set the Indent property to true:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create (outputStream, settings);
```

Comment: Well at the moment i dont write it to a file i just show it in a messagebox so all i got is a string..

Comment: @Petoj - fine; write it to a StringWriter, then call ToString() on the StringWriter

Answer (score 1):

You can load the string into an XDocument object and save it to a string again:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(writer);
string readable = writer.ToString();
```

That will give you the xml formatted this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<element1>
    <element2>some data</element2>
</element1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

```
XmlWriterSettings
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx

you can define Indent and IndentChars

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have tagged C# and VB.NET both. So my answer will be for both of them.

You can define function which get XML string as a parameter in type of String.

Let's say;

You created a function as :

[VB]

```
Private Function PrettyXML(XMLString As String) As String    
      Dim sw As New StringWriter()
      Dim xw As New XMLWriter(sw)
      xw.Formatiing = Formatting.Indented
      xw.Indentation = 4

      Dim doc As New XMLDocument
      doc.LoadXML(XMLString)
      doc.Save(xw)
      Return sw.ToString()    
End Function
```

Then you can simpyl call this function as:

```
Dim myXML As String = "<element1><element2>some data</element2></element1>"
Dim myPrettyXML As String
myPrettyXML = PrettyXML(myPrettyXML)
```

[C#]

```
Private String PrettyXML(string XMLString)
   {
      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      XMLTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
      xw.Formatiing = Formatting.Indented;
      xw.Indentation = 4;
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.Save(xm);
      return sw.ToString();
   }
```

Then you can simply call this function as:

```
string myXML =   "<element1><element2>some data</element2></element1>";
string myPrettyXML = "";
myPrettyXML = PrettyXML(myPrettyXML);
```

NOTE: I have not tried C# version, but it should work.

Hope this helps..

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Also, how is this any better than the other answers, some from four years ago?

Comment: @JohnSaunders this has one thing that the other answers dont provide you can specify how many spaces to indent with, i wont mark it as the answer after all this time but its wort a +1!